# How do I set up mailto for bcc only

Tags: html, email, mailto

I have a mailto link that I would like to populate the bcc only. Is that possible?

Comment: [Syntax of a 'mailto' URI](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6068#section-2) (and [ABNF](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5234))

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`mailto:?bcc=mailaddress` would do it!

Comment: While the other post has some good info, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

Some examples, with actual HTML Code included, follow:

Simple MailTo

`<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu">`

MailTo with Multiple Recipients

`<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu,ASTARK1@UNL.EDU">`

MailTo with Subject

`<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?subject=Comments from MailTo Syntax Page">`

MailTo with a Copy

`<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?cc=ASTARK1@UNL.EDU">`

MailTo with a Blind Copy

`<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?bcc=ASTARK1@UNL.EDU">`

MailTo with message already started in Body

`<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?body=I am having trouble finding information on ">`

MailTo with multiline message in Body

`<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?body=The message's first paragraph.%0A%0aSecond paragraph.%0A%0AThird Paragraph.">`

[source](http://zoomquiet.org/res/scrapbook/ZqSKM/data/20100419224556/)

Comment: Nice copy/paste. Did you even read the question? This is exactly what MrM does NOT want.

Comment: @Perplexor Yes, did you read my answer? see `?bcc=ASTARK1@UNL.EDU">` which is the same as provided in the other answer. And I provided my source.

Comment: I sure did. The question was if it's possible to create a mailto-link with bcc-address(es) and WITHOUT a "normal" recipient address. None of your examples did that.

Comment: @Perplexor Dont really see anything wrong with going above and beyond, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Outlook needs a semicolon instead of commas to separate mail addresses.

Comment: source is broken :(

Comment: @macool you can easily find that example on other pages... imho people should just use the wayback machine for more permanent links, e.g. http://web.archive.org/web/20170217092344/https://support.blue.net.au/support/best-use-of-email-links-on-web-pages/